# How to set flex item height equally

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container and two flex box items: `item-img` and `item-content`. `item-img` have an image in it. I want `item-img` have height equal the height of `item-content` and the image will cover all space of it.

It means the `item-img`'s height is set **based on** the `item-content`'s height.  The `item-content`'s height is not fixed and may much bigger or much smaller than the height of the image.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  border: solid 1px #123;
}

.flex-item {
  max-width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.item-img {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item-img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item item-content">
    <p>This is conent with text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `height: 100%` and `max-width: 100%` to `img` and position the image *absolutely* inside the `item-img` (so that the container always takes the height of the `item-content`) - see demo below:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  border: solid 1px #123;
}

.flex-item {
  max-width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.item-img {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  /*object-fit: cover;*/
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item-img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item item-content">
    <p>This is content with text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p> 
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item-img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item item-content">
    <p>This is content with text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: Adding a container for the `img` and *positioning* it along with `object-fit: cover` and `width: 100%` for the `img` - demo below:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  border: solid 1px #123;
}

.flex-item {
  max-width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.item-img {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.item-img div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item-img">
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item item-content">
    <p>This is content with text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p> 
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item-img">
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item item-content">
    <p>This is content with text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <p>more text</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```