# CSS to have the same width for two divs

Tags: css

[image]
So I am trying to create a responsive CSS for two `div`s. The first `div` is for the summary and the second `div` is for the summary description. How can I make the second `div` to be right underneath the first `div` while having the second `div` to get wrapped if the content in the second `div` exceeds the width of the first `div`s?

```css
div.firstdiv {
  padding: 60px 0;
}

div.seconddiv {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstdiv">This is a test for customer issues & solutions
  <div class="seconddiv">We need to address the customer issues and provide them the appropriate solutions based on issue priority
  </div>
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. Can you clarify and check your markup ?

Comment: @G-Cyr He wants the second `div` to be underneath the first `div`. He also wants to wrap the text if it exceeds the width of the text. (I think)

Comment: this trick shoud do it; https://stackoverflow.com/a/55041133/8620333 (inline-block on parent and min-width:100% width:0 on the second text)

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the question itself. This is how elements behave naturally. There is no need to have your second div be inside your first, just have them as siblings, like so:

```
<div class="firstdiv">
   This is a test for customer issues & solutions
</div>
<div class="seconddiv">
   We need to address the customer issues and provide them the appropriate solutions based on issue priority
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
.firstdiv, .seconddiv {
  width:100%; // or whatever you'd like the width to be
  margin:10px // again, whatever you'd like.
}
```

By default, the `seconddiv` element will show below the `firstdiv` element, the widths will be equal, and the text will wrap.

Side note, you should wrap the text in a `p` tag or similar instead of just having it floating inside your `div`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something with display grid, if you are willing to have a fixed size in the first div.

The solution is having both divs within the same wrapper and use CSS Grid in the wrapper div. Like this:

```css
 div.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, 300px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="firstdiv">
   This is a test for customer issues & solutions
  </div>
  <div class="seconddiv">We need to address the customer issues and provide them the appropriate solutions based on issue priority
  </div>
</div>
```