# Make a flex column of a height of its sibling column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two flex columns with some content. I want the first column height to always be equal to the height of the second column, and use `overflow: auto` if it has more content than the other column. One important note is that I don't want to use absolute positioning. Below is what I am after:

```css
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content-1 {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content-2 {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      
      <div class="cover">
        <div class="content-1"></div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    
      <div class="content-2"></div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve the same without the absolutely positioned element nested in the first col? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use flex box property for display to col parent as well as to childs so even those fill parent container fully.

Comment: @Manjunath, I'd appreciate a functional example because it fails to work for me.

Comment: Ok, found a way if anybody wonders. I should change the styles of the `.cover` component to just `height: 0;` and remove its absolute positioning and related style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea I used in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58488563/8620333) where you can rely on the `min-height:100%;height:0;` trick.  The `height:0` will force the element to not affect the height of the container and `min-height:100%` will force it to be equal to the height defined by the sibling element:

```css
.cover {
  height:0;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content-1 {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content-2 {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      
      <div class="cover">
        <div class="content-1"></div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    
      <div class="content-2"></div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right, that's what I came up with too and commented above. Marking this as the best answer.