# <select multiple> ruins CSS grid

Tags: css, html-select, css-grid

Please run the following simple grid layout example, featuring a grid cell that is a  `<select multiple></select>`:

```css
.grid-container {
  align-items: start;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-column-count-2 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
.grid-row-count-2 {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
}

.col-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.col-2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.row-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.row-2 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.rowspan-2 {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.align-self-end {
  align-self: end;
}

.align-self-stretch {
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container grid-column-count-2 grid-row-count-2">
  <select multiple class="col-1 row-1 rowspan-2 align-self-stretch">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>E</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-1" />
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-2 align-self-end" />
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-1" />
</div>
```

The expected result is that the `select element` spans two rows, the height of each being defined by the `<input type="text" />` elements in column 2, just like it looks if I replace the `select` with a simple `div`:

```css
.grid-container {
  align-items: start;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-column-count-2 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
.grid-row-count-2 {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
}

.col-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.col-2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.row-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.row-2 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.rowspan-2 {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.align-self-end {
  align-self: end;
}

.align-self-stretch {
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container grid-column-count-2 grid-row-count-2">
  <div class="col-1 row-1 rowspan-2 align-self-stretch" style="background-color: #f2f2f2; border: 1px solid #bbb; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-1" />
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-2 align-self-end" />
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-1" />
</div>
```

Question:

How do I style the `select` element in such a way that it does

- a) have a fixed `min-height` of let's say `30px`;
- b) aside from that just get its `height` from the grid cell that it is (like the div in the second example does)

**In other words:**

How do I prevent the `select` element from affecting the row height in the grid?

Note: I cannot work with fixed-height rows.

Note 2: If a solution rather lies in a different approach as of how to define the `grid-template-rows` for the grid, I'm open to that as well (as long as it allows arbitrary content to define the row height).
I'm unsure if my question is clear enough. Please leave a comment explaining what is unclear, and I will try my best and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenting, I found a way to solve the issue:

```
select {
  height: 24px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

seems to solve the problem. What seems very counter-intuitive about this is that `min-height` in this case exceeds (overwrites) height, effectively **increasing** it.

```css
select {
  height: 30px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.grid-container {
  align-items: start;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-column-count-2 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
.grid-row-count-2 {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
}

.col-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.col-2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.row-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.row-2 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.rowspan-2 {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.align-self-end {
  align-self: end;
}

.align-self-stretch {
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container grid-column-count-2 grid-row-count-2">
  <select multiple class="col-1 row-1 rowspan-2 align-self-stretch">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>E</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-1" />
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-2 align-self-end" />
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-1" />
</div>
```

Comment: I understand your solution. It makes your layout work how you want. But I don't get why you need `align-items` and `align-self` here? They are making no difference, because you've eliminated all free space. Why have them?

Comment: @Michael_B Because in my real world problem, the elements are alot more complex and involve custom elements that create labels which can be aligned north, east, west and south. Imagine an input type=text with a north aligned label alongside and input type=checkbox with an east aligned label. That is why I need to be able to control vertical row alignment. (The checkbox would need to reside at the bottom of it's cell if it is in the same row as the described input type=text with the north aligned label).

Comment: This is the logical solution I would consider (I am a bit late this time). I used this trick before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58488563/8620333 and it also work with width too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55041133/8620333 .. the trick is that only height is considered to define the layout and since min-height is used with percentage it will be calculated later (since we need a reference) and will define the final height of the item but play no role in the height of grid tracks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding `size` attribute to `<select>`. in your case between `size="1"` and `size="3"` will offer similar result to what needed.

```css
.grid-container {
  align-items: start;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-column-count-2 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.grid-row-count-2 {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
}

.col-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.col-2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.row-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.row-2 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.rowspan-2 {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.align-self-end {
  align-self: end;
}

.align-self-stretch {
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container grid-column-count-2 grid-row-count-2">
  <select multiple size="3" class="col-1 row-1 rowspan-2 align-self-stretch">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>E</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-1" />
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-2 align-self-end" />
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-1" />
</div>
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this does work, even if setting size to 1 or 2. Good spot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `select` element with multiple `options` is not disrupting the grid rows.

The problem is `align-items: start` on the grid container, and `align-self: end` on the penultimate `input`, which are packing the inputs within the row.

In the image below, in the second column, notice how the inputs are not taking up the full height of the row. That's the `align-*` properties doing their work.

[image]

You didn't see the same behavior with your DIV example because that version had no content. Here it is, with 4 lines of content, like your first example:

```css
.grid-container {
  align-items: start;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-column-count-2 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.grid-row-count-2 {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
}

.col-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.col-2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.row-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.row-2 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.rowspan-2 {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.align-self-end {
  align-self: end;
}

.align-self-stretch {
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container grid-column-count-2 grid-row-count-2">
  <div class="col-1 row-1 rowspan-2 align-self-stretch" style="background-color: #f2f2f2; border: 1px solid #bbb; overflow-y: scroll;"><span>div A</span><br>
    <span>div B</span><br><span>div C</span><br><span>div D</span><br></div>
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-1" />
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-2 align-self-end" />
  <input type="text" class="col-2 row-1" />
</div>
```

Comment: If you remove `align-items: start;` from `.grid-container` and `align-self-end` from the list of CSS classes on the second `input`, the input elements suddenly grow vertically, which solves one problem at the cost of creating another. If your assumption were correct and the select wouldn't influence the row heights, any vertical alignment of the other cells wouldn't make any difference!

Comment: Your question came down to this: *"How do I prevent the select element from influencing the row height in the grid?"* I pointed out that the problem you're describing was not in the row heights. It's the height of the grid items that left the appearance of a vertical gap.

Comment: Yes, and as stated, assuming the select element would not affect row heights, the two rows would be just as high as the input elements, regardless of their `align-self`. In other words, I need the inputs to define row height (and not change their height via the grid).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The `align-*` properties are shrinking the inputs inside their rows. The row heights are full size, only having he `grid-gap` separating them.

Comment: Basically I need the input height not affected by the grid either. The height of the input elements should not be altered by the row height of the cell they are. The vertical gap between the inputs needs to 10px, both in the CSS and also visually.

Comment: The height of the grid is being set by the tallest item. In this case, that's the select element. This element then goes on to define the height of the grid rows. The row heights then remain constant across the grid. The inputs have no impact on row height (unless they eventually grow taller than the select element).

Comment: That was exactly my problem - the total grid height was altered by the select (being the tallest). I needed a way for the select to have a) a fixed minimum height, and b) aside from that minimum height, always **take** its height from the cell that it is in (and never extend a cell beyond that minimum height).