# Preventing a <pre> from wrapping inside of a table

Tags: css, html-table, multiple-columns, word-wrap, pre

I have a table with two columns. One has some property names and the other has descriptions, including pre tags. I need the pre tags to not wrap and instead scroll to see overflow. I also need the first column to be sized based on the largest property name. I can't get the two to play nicely with each other.

For example I can get the first column to size based on the content but the pre won't scroll:

```css
.main-content {
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
pre {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <table border="0" class="config">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Property</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="config-name">name</td>
        <td class="config-description">

          <p>Foo bar talking about some random things related to our code here in the paragraph:</p>
          <pre>// some really long code section here that should have its own scroll bar (and not wrap) some really long code section here that should have its own scroll bar (and not wrap)</pre>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I can also get the pre to scroll but then I can't get the first column to resize:

```css
.main-content {
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
th:first-of-type {
  width: 15%; /* Faking it here - the size of the first td/th should be based on the largest */
} 
pre {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <table border="0" class="config">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Property</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="config-name">name</td>
        <td class="config-description">

          <p>Foo bar talking about some random things related to our code here in the paragraph:</p>
          <pre>// some really long code section here that should have its own scroll bar (and not wrap) some really long code section here that should have its own scroll bar (and not wrap)</pre>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I can get both working while retaining a table layout? I know how to do it with other methods like grid and flexbox, that's not what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consisder `width:0;min-width:100%;` trick on the `pre`. The idea is that the `width:0` will disable the contribution of `pre` on defining the width of the container then `min-width:100%` will force it to fill all the space:

```css
.main-content {
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

th:first-of-type {
  white-space:nowrap;
} 
pre {
  overflow: auto;
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <table border="0" class="config">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Property</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="config-name">name</td>
        <td class="config-description">

          <p>Foo bar talking about some random things related to our code here in the paragraph:</p>
          <pre>// some really long code section here that should have its own scroll bar (and not wrap) some really long code section here that should have its own scroll bar (and not wrap)</pre>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Related question: [How to match width of text to width of dynamically sized image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55040250/8620333)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see to do this is to wrap your `<pre>` in a `<div>` with `overflow: auto` and set the cell to `display: grid`

```css
.main-content {
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.config-name {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.config-description {
  display: grid;
}

.config-description div {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <table border="0" class="config">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Property</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="config-name">name</td>
        <td class="config-description">

          <p>Foo bar talking about some random things related to our code here in the paragraph:</p>
          <div>
            <pre>// some really long code section here that should have its own scroll bar (and not wrap) some really long code section here that should have its own scroll bar (and not wrap)</pre>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="config-name">longer&nbsp;property&nbsp;name</td>
        <td class="config-description">

          <p>Just another description, this one without a &lt;pre&gt;</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The combination of `display: grid` with the div container for the pre is sufficient. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ZachSaucier chaging the display of td from table-cell to grid may give some unwanted result (don't have any example though but you should pay attention)