# I want to have a single child item mandate the width for all other elements

Tags: css, reactjs

In React I have an `inline-flex` parent element that contains a hyperlinked image and a support email URL. I want the support email URL element's width to **MANDATE** the width of the parent element and subsequently of the image as well. Meaning all the element width's must be the same as the support element's width.

This is what I have so far but it's not working. I'm not very good at CSS:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ProviderContainer = styled.div`
    margin: auto
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;

    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #747162;
`;

const ProviderSupport = styled.a`
    margin:10px 0;
    display: inline-table;

    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #747162;
`

const ImageContainer = styled.div`
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #747162;
    flex-basis: 100%
`

const Provider = (props) => (
    <ProviderContainer>
        <ImageContainer>
            <a href={props.ProviderLink}>
                <img style={{width:'100%'}} src={props.ProviderLogo}></img>
            </a>
        </ImageContainer>
        <ProviderSupport href={`mailto:${props.ProviderSupport}`}>{props.ProviderSupport}</ProviderSupport>
    </ProviderContainer>
);

Provider.propTypes = {
    ProviderLink: PropTypes.string,
    ProviderLogo: PropTypes.string,
    ProviderSupport: PropTypes.string
};

export default Provider;
```

The borders are just so I can get an idea of the box size
This is the issue that can pop up if the image is too big:[image]

Here's a transpiled fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/uj5d4621/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowed from this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55040250/how-to-match-width-of-text-to-width-of-dynamically-sized-image-title)

```css
.parent {
  background: pink;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin:1em;
  vertical-align:top;
}

a, img {
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200" alt=""></a>
  <div class="description">
    http://www.fillmurray.com/
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200" alt=""></a>
  <div class="description">
    http://www.longhyperlinknamegoeshere.com/
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer does not work in the fiddle? Think it has to do with the support URL being in a hyperlink element not a div

Comment: Got this to work with some fiddling ;) https://jsfiddle.net/6fhz9mcx/1/

Answer (score 0):

I do not work with react so I have a little trouble reading your code but in my opinion it is enough to add a width to your element.

```js
const ProviderSupport = styled.a`
    margin:10px 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #747162;
`
```

Comment: Nope, that just changes the width of the support element to match the image element

Comment: Can you have an online exemple to show the code, 
then it would be easier for me to help you.

Comment: Edited my question with a fiddle