# How to have an HTML container fit the width of a single child-element, while restricting the width of another child-element?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple DIV container that has 2 div child elements in it.
I want the 1st element to set the width of the parent container, and the 2nd element to fit the available width.
I have this simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekvpwjmd/60/) that shows my attempts. I want the red element's width to match the blue one.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    first element
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    second element with more characters
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe a different layout will help me get what I want, or some specific css trick. I'd be happy with anything that might work.

Comment: better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55041133/8620333

Comment: You are right @TemaniAfif - this is a more elegant solution than the one I marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

A style is added to the parent element `display: table;`

On the second child element is added `display: table-caption;` and `caption-side: bottom;` so as not to stand in the first position.

It is not necessary to add style to the first child element, but I have added it `display: inline;`

I hope I have been helpful

```css
.container {
    background-color: green;
    display: table;
}

.first {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline;
}

.second {
    background-color: red;
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">
        first element dfsf fd ssdf g
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        second element with more characters
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible that you make the row into add the class no-gutters and col-div put into an other class p-0 i think your will be solve the matter.

or your first child div into add the new classes p-0 and no-gutters
thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. I do not see that your anwser is related in any way to the OP's problem. Also I got no idea what you talking about but again its not related to the original problem in the first place.