# Why using SVG in <table> cell forces table to 100% width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm building table that should display data in a reasonable way. And don't take 100% width if it's not needed.

The problem is that in one column I use line chart, and when I build that chart with `div` it works well, but when I use `SVG` the table takes 100% (I prefer to use SVG as it more flexible).

Below is how the table should look like (and it looks like that if `div` used instead of `SVG` to display line chart):

[image]

And that's how the table looks when `SVG` is used, taking the whole page width

[image]

I assume it's because `SVG` tries to grab as much space as possilbe and it inflate table to 100%.

**How it could be fixed?** I'm using **table fixed layout and fixed percentage column width**. I don't know the data that's going to be displayed in the table and the table width beforehand, table should determine the optimal width automatically.

Simplified example:

```css
table { table-layout: fixed; max-wdith: 100% }
tr > * { border: 1px solid black; }
svg { display: block; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 50%;">a</th>
    <th style="width: 50%;">b</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <svg height="1rem" width="100%">
        <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="black"/>
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

P.S.

One possible way to fix it would be to hide `SVG` line plots initially, and let the table be rendered without `SVG`. And then after 1ms or so, when the table is rendered, measure table width and set that width explicitly with JS. And then display the `SVG` lines, and table will be limited by the explicit widht measured before. But maybe there's easier way?

Comment: `<th style="width=50%;">` should be `<th style="width: 50%;">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a trick to disable the contribution of the SVG to the width. You simply set `width:0` and add `min-width:100%` to recover the full width again:

It should work on your real example (I have tested)

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  max-wdith: 100%
}

tr>* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:50%;">aaa</th>
    <th style="width:50%;">bbb</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <svg height="1rem" >
        <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="black"/>
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:50%;">aaa</th>
    <th style="width:50%;">bbbbbbb</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <svg height="1rem">
        <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="black"/>
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Related: [How to match width of text to width of dynamically sized image/title?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55040250/8620333)

Answer (score 1):

I've found `svg` to be finicky without viewbox — running from memory, svg defaults to height/width 300x150 though that may be outdated. Also, fixed a typo in your `th` style.

Code below unfortunately creates a relatively sized, proportionally resizing svg.

```css
table { table-layout: fixed; max-width: 100% }
tr > * { border: 1px solid black; }
svg { display: block; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 50%;">a</th>
    <th style="width: 50%;">b</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <svg style="height: auto; width: 100%;" viewbox="0 0 100 10">
        <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="50%" height="50%" fill="black"/>
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```