# how to add a full width form input to a css grid layout and not cause the column to grow

Tags: html, css, forms, css-grid

I have a simple css grid layout and when I add an form `<input />` it causes the column to grow. I'd like the input to fill the column but not make it grow.

I've tried adding `min-width: 0` and `overflow: hidden` and neither/both stop the column from growing. If I make the input smaller with a `max-width` then the column returns to the size I want it to be (the smallest to contain the text). But I'd like the form input to fill the whole column.

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr">
  <div style="background: red">Hello</div>
  <div style="background: green">yes I'm a big long</div>
  <div style="background: blue">no</div>
  <div style="background: red">Hello</div>
  <div style="background: green"><input placeholder="input" /></div>
  <div style="background: blue">no</div>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like.

[image: grid layout without and with form input]

I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/arkarkark/pen/YzQNMQP) to play around with this. I only need it to work with Chrome, but I've verified I get the same behavior with Chrome, Safari and Firefox on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `width:0;min-width:100%;` (related question: [How to match width of text to width of dynamically sized image/title?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55040250/8620333))

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr">
  <div style="background: red">Hello</div>
  <div style="background: green">yes I'm a big long</div>
  <div style="background: blue">no</div>
  <div style="background: red">Hello</div>
  <div style="background: green">yes</div>
  <div style="background: blue">no</div>
</div>
<p> adding the input </p>

<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr">
  <div style="background: red">Hello</div>
  <div style="background: green">yes I'm a big long</div>
  <div style="background: blue">no</div>
  <div style="background: red">Hello</div>
  <div style="background: green"><input style="width:0;min-width:100%;" placeholder="input" /></div>
  <div style="background: blue">no</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to defines the number of rows/columns in the grid as well as their dimension.

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto 120px 1fr">
  <div style="background: red">Hello</div>
  <div style="background: green">yes I'm a big long</div>
  <div style="background: blue">no</div>
  <div style="background: red">Hello</div>
  <div style="background: green"><input placeholder="input" /></div>
  <div style="background: blue">no</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the number of columns is fine. as you can see if you click on the codepen. Changing the 2nd column from `auto` to `120px` defeats the purpose, I need that column to grow/shrink to fit the text (but not to change size because of the form input).