# Prevent grid items containing an image from stretching other grid items

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

I've seen a bunch of similar looking questions and went through them all, but none of the solutions seem to work for my problem.

I have a `main` grid and a bunch of sections within it. One contains the visual result - an image (with a `filter` manipulated via the controls in the other sections, but that part isn't really relevant here).

The problem is that the `section` containing the `img` stretches the other sections.

```css
* { margin: 0 }

main {
  --space: .5em;
  --imcol: min(40%, 400px);
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: var(--space);
  grid-template-columns: 
    min(100% - var(--space) - var(--imcol), 32em) 
    var(--imcol);
  padding: var(--space)
}

section { background: pink }
.ctrl { padding: inherit }
.result { grid-area: 1/ 2/ span 2 }

/* often found this as a fix, but it doesn't work */
section, figure, img {
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 100%
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class='ctrl'>
    <header><h2>Some heading</h2></header>
    <div class='wrap'>
      <input id='boo' name'oo' type='checkbox' checked/>
      <label for='boo'>boo</label>
      <input id='foo' name'oo' type='checkbox' checked/>
      <label for='foo'>foo</label>
      <input id='moo' name'oo' type='checkbox'/>
      <label for='moo'>moo</label>
    </div>
    <div>Jelly-o danish cupcake jelly-o bonbon lollipop danish chocolate bar. Oat cake cheesecake marshmallow chocolate bar caramels macaroon gummi bears. Gingerbread cotton candy topping carrot cake fruitcake tart.</div>
    <button>action</button>
  </section>
  <section class='ctrl'>
    <header><h2>Some other heading</h2></header>
    <div class='wrap'>
      <input id='mew' name'ew' type='checkbox' checked/>
      <label for='mew'>mew</label>
      <input id='few' name'ew' type='checkbox'/>
      <label for='few'>few</label>
      <input id='pew' name'ew' type='checkbox'/>
      <label for='pew'>pew</label>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class='result'>
    <figure>
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1707767787271-b00e648a61e4?w=400' alt='lions'>
    </figure>
  </section>
</main>
```

The only way I can think of that would give me the result I want would be to absolutely position the image and set `overflow: hidden` on the `figure`.

```css
* { margin: 0 }

main {
  --space: .5em;
  --imcol: min(40%, 400px);
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: var(--space);
  grid-template-columns: 
    min(100% - var(--space) - var(--imcol), 32em) 
    var(--imcol);
  padding: var(--space)
}

section { background: pink }
.ctrl { padding: inherit }
.result { grid-area: 1/ 2/ span 2 }

figure {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class='ctrl'>
    <header><h2>Some heading</h2></header>
    <div class='wrap'>
      <input id='boo' name'oo' type='checkbox' checked/>
      <label for='boo'>boo</label>
      <input id='foo' name'oo' type='checkbox' checked/>
      <label for='foo'>foo</label>
      <input id='moo' name'oo' type='checkbox'/>
      <label for='moo'>moo</label>
    </div>
    <div>Jelly-o danish cupcake jelly-o bonbon lollipop danish chocolate bar. Oat cake cheesecake marshmallow chocolate bar caramels macaroon gummi bears. Gingerbread cotton candy topping carrot cake fruitcake tart.</div>
    <button>action</button>
  </section>
  <section class='ctrl'>
    <header><h2>Some other heading</h2></header>
    <div class='wrap'>
      <input id='mew' name'ew' type='checkbox' checked/>
      <label for='mew'>mew</label>
      <input id='few' name'ew' type='checkbox'/>
      <label for='few'>few</label>
      <input id='pew' name'ew' type='checkbox'/>
      <label for='pew'>pew</label>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class='result'>
    <figure>
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1707767787271-b00e648a61e4?w=400' alt='lions'>
    </figure>
  </section>
</main>
```

Is there any way of getting this result without taking the image out of the document flow?

Comment: `height:0; min-height: 100%` to the figure element?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The first snippet *is* doing that and it doesn't work...

Comment: not exactly, you need to set height to 0 (not min-height) and min-height to 100% : https://jsfiddle.net/s479j083/

Comment: Oh, I see the difference now! Can you drop it an answer, so I can accept it and the question shows up as answered?

Comment: I am redirecting to another answer where I am adding all the cases (including the out of the flow one) and also another one using `contain` that may also work here

Comment: the same trick also work in the horizontal direction using width: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55040250/8620333

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work with `height: 0%` instead of `height: 0`?

Comment: because when using a percentage, you need a reference for the height and that reference doesn't exist initially so the height will fall to auto (the size of the image). In this case, the image height will get used to define the size. With 0, it's a length so it's like defining 0px and you explicitly say that the image has no size. min-height: 100% will have the same behavior, first it will fall to auto (no reference) and in a second iteration we have a reference (due to the stretch alignment) and this will force the image to be 100%.

Comment: So we have a first iteration with `height: 0;min-height: auto` then a few calculation then another iteration with `min-height: 100%` that will use the height calculated in the first iteration where the image was not contributing because it has a height equal to 0.

Comment: speaking about the stretch alignment, if you add `align-items: start;` to grid container, the trick will no more work because we no more have a reference for the figure and in such case you are obliged to apply the trick to the section element instead because we still have a reference there